# How to custom a logical validation for entity insertion on android room

Tags: android, validation, kotlin, android-room

I have an Entity like this:

```
data class Person(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id", index = true) var userId: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") var firstName: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "mid_name") var midName: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") var lastName: String = ""
) {
    public fun fullName(): String {
        return "$firstName $midName $lastName"
    }
}
```

I know that I can set a "not null" attribute to each named property. But in my case, it's no need to fill up all the name properties, **I only want to validate the full name is blank or not** before this entity saves to the room database.

I'm practicing to use the MVVM framework, but now I'm not sure where should I put the validation. Activity/Fragment? ViewModel? Repository? or inside the Entity directly?

I think maybe I should do this in a repository so that I can prevent the wrong input before I save it to the database. But what if there is another use case that I need to validate the same thing in a different repository? If so, then the code will be duplicated in two repositories.

I've ever written ruby on rails before, there is validation function in the Model like:

```rb
# This is ruby on rails code
validate :name_validation

def name_validation
    if first_name == "" && mid_name == "" && last_name == ""
        errors.add(:name, "the name should not be totally blank")
    end
end
```

I wonder if there is a similar way to validate a property in the Entity, or there is any better practice to resolve this?

Please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe we can just use a `fullName` property directly and let it not null.

Then make a **Name class** for name processing, and **NameConveter class** for converting.

So the sample code may seems like this:

```kotlin
class Name(
    var firstName: String = "",
    var midName: String = "",
    var lastName: String = ""
) {
    public fun fullName(): String {
        return "$firstName $midName $lastName".trim()
    }
}

@Entity
data class Person(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id", index = true) var userId: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "full_name") var fullName: Name
)

class NameStringConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(value: String): Name {
        val nameStr = value.split(" ")
        return Name(nameStr[0], nameStr[1], nameStr[2])
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun nameToString(name: Name): String? {
        val fullName = name.fullName()
        // Here is the trick 
        // to make a blank full name become an invalid name for a not null property
        if (name.isNullOrBlank()) {
            return null
        } else {
            return fullName
        }
    }
}
```

So that we can access multiple name by **Name Class**, and database will help us to check the fullname now.

I know that my sample code may cause some problem such as an extra blank character in a name string, but let us focus on the fullName validation issue for now.

I figured out this solution today, I'm not sure it's a good answer or not.

I post here and open for everyone to judge it.